# How to modify partitions after install?

Tags: 12.04, windows, encryption, gparted, luks

I wanted to have Ubuntu with full disk encryption on one big partition, and Windows on a small one. In 12.04, only the Server Edition installer has full disk encryption, so I used that and then installed ubuntu-desktop. When it asked for the size, I reduced it from ~999GB to ~750gb. Now after the install, on both `gparted` and `disk utility` I see /dev/sda2 taking ~931GB, and nothing unallocated, so I can't create a partition for windows.

I got the size right, because when I right-click inside a folder, then hit 'properties', I see `Free space: ~690GB` (I don't know why it's not ~750GB, but at least it's not >900). The command `df -h` shows the same.

So what can I do? Normally I would just resize a partition with gparted to create unallocated space, then create the partition. But here I have two problems: gparted does not seem to be showing the correct values, and also it says it does not support LUKS so I'm afraid it will mess things up.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the sizes:

```
1 GB  = 109 B = 10003 B = 1,000,000,000 B
1 GiB = 230 B = 10243 B = 1,073,741,824 B
```

```
931 GiB is 999 GB
698 GiB is 750 GB
```

`Disks` report in GB.
`GParted` report in GiB.
`df -H` report in GB.
`df -h` report in GiB.
`df -BG` report in GiB.
`lsblk` report in GiB.

Also; when it comes to `df` versus the other mentioned.

GParted, Disks, lsblk reports size calculated from core HDD.

`df`, `Nautilus` etc. reports actual usable space within the file system. First off the file system has to have N bytes that match up with various calculations. I.e. divisible by X. Second space is used to keep the file system in order. Etc.

---

When it comes to your biggest issue:

What is your output from `lsblk` ?